# How to fix this Realm Exception?

Tags: xamarin, realm

After deleting some items from my db i get this -> Realms.RealmInvalidObjectException: This object is detached. Was it deleted from the realm?

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Stack Overflow! In order to help you the better way possible, provide us with some extra info on your problem: Try to isolate the piece of code causing the issue. If possible provide some context explaining what you're trying to do and the results you're getting. The error trace is helpful as well.

Comment: Well this exception means that you're trying to access objects that you have deleted from the Realm. The solution would be to keep your results in sync with your adapter using RealmChangeListener, https://github.com/realm/realm-android-adapters

Comment: @epicpandaforce thanks for your reply. I will check out how RealmChangeListener works

Comment: @EpicPandaForce im working with xamarin.forms! is this only supposed to be on the android? cause my ios crashes too.

Comment: ..........oh. Well I couldn't possibly have known that just by reading the question, could I?

Comment: @EpicPandaForce of course not! Unless you are some kind of wizard:)

Answer (score 2):

In Realm Xamarin, you have to use [RealmResult Notifications](https://realm.io/docs/xamarin/latest/#realmresult-notifications) to be notified of when there is a change to your database.

Considering Realm is zero-copy and the objects you obtain from it are just proxies to the underlying database, if you delete an object on *any* thread, then that object will be deleted on every thread in Realm's latest snapshot for the thread.

So it's best if you always make sure you're notified of changes in your result set and update the UI accordingly, and handle the case when your objects could have been deleted due to some operation (by making sure they're still valid).

Comment: Thank you very much! Im going to study and use the RealmResult Notifications!